# How to move a user to a new Organizational Unit

Tags: command-line, active-directory, command

Using the command line, how can I:

1. Move a user to a new Organizational Unit?
2. Get the current Organizational Unit of a user?

Comment: Remove tag from title; clarify acronym; tweak text of question; remove "thanks"

Answer (score 0):

1. `Get-ADUser UserName | Move-ADObject -TargetPath (Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Filter "Name -eq 'Your OU Name'")`
2. `Get-ADUser UserName | Select DistinguishedName`

This may help you: [Move Active Directory users with PowerShell](https://4sysops.com/archives/move-active-directory-users-with-powershell-2/)

Answer (score 0):

Use the ActiveDirectory-Module of Powershell:

```
Import-Module activedirectory
Move-ADObject -Identity "CN=John Doe,OU=Accounting,DC=Fabrikam,DC=com" -TargetPath "OU=NewOU,DC=Fabrikam,DC=com"
```

See:  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?linkid=291059

And:

```
Import-Module activedirectory
Get-ADUser -Identity foobar|FT DistinguishedName
```

See: https://technet.microsoft.com/library/251aa5e1-8d5d-4eda-82b5-f0092b44ec3f%28v=wps.630%29.aspx

In the second example you need to do some string handling to get the OU